# Showing that $(X) \cap (X^2,Y) \subset (X^2,XY)$ as ideals in $k[X,Y,Z]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

In my book, there is a part in a problem where we need to confirm that in $k[X,Y,Z]$ it holds that

$$(X) \cap (X^2,Y) \subset (X^2,XY)$$

Now i somehow feel a bit lost whenever i need to work with intersections of ideals. However, the proof proposes that the inclusion is given by the following observation:

If $$fX = gY^2\ \text{or}\ fX = gY,$$ then $f$ must involve $Y$ and $g$ must invole $X$, hence $fX$ is a multiple of $XY$.

The latter makes sense, but how does one get to that point in the first place? Why do we consider $$fX = gY^2$$? And how does that relate to

$$(X) \cap (X^2,Y) \subset (X^2,XY)$$ ?

Could someone elaborate? How would i need to approach problems like this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in (X)\cap (X^2, Y)$, then $a=fX$ and $a=g_1X^2+g_2Y.$  Now equate
$$fX=g_1X^2+g_2Y.$$

So $X(f-g_1X)=g_2Y$. Since $k[X, Y]$ is a UFD, $X|g_2,$ say $g_2=g_3X$.

So $a=g_1X^2+g_2Y=g_1X^2+g_3XY\in (X^2, XY).$

Comment: Thank you @Evans Gambit. I've tried to apply this to a few examples and it seems like this worked for all my examples. Where do need to be careful though? I feel like this can't be applied every time, can it?

Comment: We crucially used the unique factorization property of a polynomial ring over a field. As long as it is there we are fine. If the co-ordinate ring we had were not a UFD, we would have been stuck.

Comment: Of course, thank you. I was just wondering since it holds that if $A$ is a UFD, $A[X]$ is a UFD, hence $A[X][Y] = A[X,Y]$ is a UFD and so on.... therefore $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ is always a UFD for all $n$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Sorry, one last question. I tried to apply this approach to showing that $$(X,Z)\cap (Y^2,X-YZ)\subseteq (XY,X-YZ)$$ but this time, i couldn't do it. Would i need to look for another approach in this case?

Comment: I tried to do this new question for a bit. If it is true, it is not so trivial as the above example. You can post it as a separate question if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Evans, i will consider posting it as a question. Ty